HTTPS hearders but HTTP URL in FastAPI and Cloud Run
I created a FastAPI app and I can access the Swagger UI autodocs at https://cloudrundomain.app/docs. When I send an HTTPS request using the Swagger UI, the request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-Proto") is HTTPS, but the request.url is http://cloudrundomain (the bottom of my problem is that HTTPException is HTTP, but I think it starts there).
I don't think it's a good idea, but I tried doing what you could see below. The "Modify the scheme to HTTPS to avoid mixed content issues" triggers, but the redirection then fails.
@app.middleware("http")
async def force_https(request: Request, call_next):
   # Check the X-Forwarded-Proto header to determine if the request is HTTP
   forwarded_proto = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-Proto")

   if forwarded_proto == "http":
       print("Redirect to HTTPS")
       return RedirectResponse(url=f"https://{request.url.hostname}{request.url.path}")

   # Ensure URLs are constructed using HTTPS
   # Modify request.url to use HTTPS if necessary
   if forwarded_proto == "https" and request.url.scheme == "http":
       print("Modify the scheme to HTTPS to avoid mixed content issues")
       return RedirectResponse(url=f"https://{request.url.hostname}{request.url.path}")

   # Proceed with the request if it's already HTTPS or after the redirect
   response = await call_next(request)
   return response 


I found a solution by referring to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/369.
To be more specific, I changed the way I was starting my FastAPI web app. Previously, I used:
fastapi  run --workers 4 app/main.py
I switched to using directly Uvicorn with the following command:
uvicorn your_app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --proxy-headers --forwarded-allow-ips "*"

Note that, as described in this answer, instead of trusting headers from all IPs using the * wildcard (i.e., --forwarded-allow-ips='*'), it would be more safe to trust only proxy headers from the IP of your reverse proxy server.

This is not a solution but a bandaid. You are processing the Proxy headers incorrectly. For Cloud Run, there is a proxy in front of your service called the GFE. That means you need to handle multiple values for the Proxy headers if you are so inclined. Cloud Run automatically handles HTTP redirects at the GFE, your application does not need to do anything. I recommend that you delete this answer and do your homework before posting incorrect information that will confuse future readers.

Here is a link for the automatic redirect: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request#redirect
